# Stopping an AudioPlayer in a different ViewController

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer, viewcontroller

I have a main menu sound file playing in an AVAudioPlayer.

I wanted to create an option button that takes me to another view controller. When I click on the switch to have an option to turn the main menu sound "off". How can I stop the audio playing?

How can I access the audio player in a different ViewController?

Let me know if you need more info. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Create a Singleton class in which you add the player and control it from:

```
import AVFoundation

class Singleton {
    static let sharedInstance = Singleton()
    private var player: AVAudioPlayer?

    func play() {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Sound", withExtension: "mp3") else { return }

        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)

            guard let player = player else { return }

            player.play()

        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    func stop() {
        player?.stop()
    }
}
```

Whenever you want to start the sound just call:

```
Singleton.sharedInstance.play()
```

Whenever you want to stop the sound just call:

```
Singleton.sharedInstance.stop()
```

This can be called from all controllers.

Comment: Thanks you save my life

Answer (score 0):

You could create the audio player as a class and instantiate a shared instance of that class.

```
class PageDataSource {
    var page: Int?
    var angels = [Angel]()
    var angelsToSave = [Int]()
    var myName: String?

    static let sharedInstance = PageDataSource()
    private init() {}
}
```

With that `sharedInstance` you can call this ONE object in all of your views and edit the it there. I've only ever used it as a way to share data between all views but I would think you could use it to do what you're looking for. Here is an example of how it works:

```
  class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            PageDataSource.sharedInstance.page = 1
     }
}
```

As soon as that runs, that data is accessible from anywhere in your app. You can test it by calling `print(PageDataSource.sharedInstance.page!)`

Another option is to have all of the code for your Audio Player in an `extension` of a common class that you use like a custom implementation of `UIViewController`. If you do that, you can call all of the functions you need in any `UIViewController` that supports the AVAudioPlayer framework (imports, delegates etc.,)

I do this frequently for `alerts` that I use :

```
extension: UIViewController {

    func doCrudAlert(_ title: String, _ message: String, _ button: String, _  completion: (() -> Swift.Void)? = nil)  {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let buttonAction = UIAlertAction(title: button, style: .default) { (action) in
            completion?()
            return
        }
        alert.addAction(buttonAction)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

With that bit of code I can call `doCrudAlert("Title String", "Message!!!!", "Button Title", nil )` from any `UIViewController`